# How to click on a checkbox covered by a link Selenium WebDriver in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

```
<div class="checkbox_tick fs-12 mb-14 js-agreement-wrapper">
<div class="input checkbox">
<input type="hidden" name="agreement" value="0">
<label for="agreement">
<input type="checkbox" name="agreement" value="1" class="js-checkbox js-agree checkbox-inited" id="agreement">
"Some Text on the page"
<a href="/pages/agreement" target="_blank" class="black">Some Text on the page</a></label></div>                            
</div>
```

I used both the CSS selector and the XPath request. Once the link is opened, it doesn't check the checkbox

`driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.checkbox_tick.fs-12.mb-14.js-agreement-wrapper")).Click();`

`driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='step1']/div[4]/div[2]/div/form/div[3]/div")).Click();`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the below XPath, this might help to click on the checkbox

```
//input[@id='agreement' and @type = 'checkbox']
```

OR

```
//input[@name='agreement' and @type = 'checkbox']

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='agreement' and @type = 'checkbox']")).Click();


driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input#agreement")).Click();
```

put some wait before clicking on the checkbox you can use `explicitWait`

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));
var chckBox = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//input[@id='agreement' and @type = 'checkbox']")));
chckBox.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to click it with JS

```
public void JavaScriptClick(IWebElement element)
{
    IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
    executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
}
```